# TypeError: new(): invalid data type 'str' from ( Training a Deep learning model using import torch )

Tags: python, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

The actual code

```
import torch
from torch import nn
import re


# Define the vocabulary of the input and output sequences
vocab = ["The", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog", ".",
         "old", "man", "and", "sea", "A", "story", "as", "time", "cat", "in", "hat",
         "To", "be", "or", "not", "to", "be"]

# Define the input and output sizes
input_size = len(vocab)
output_size = len(vocab)

# Define the other parameters of the  model
hidden_size = 256
n_layers = 2
dropout = 0.2
batch_size = 64
learning_rate = 0.01



class MyLSTMModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, dropout, batch_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.dropout = dropout
        self.batch_size = batch_size

        # Define the LSTM cell to use in the  layer
        self.lstm_cell = nn.LSTM(input_size=input_size, hidden_size=hidden_size, num_layers=num_layers, dropout=dropout)

        # Define the architecture of the  using the LSTM cell
        self.model = nn.LSTM(input_size=input_size, hidden_size=hidden_size, num_layers=num_layers, dropout=dropout)

    def forward(self, input_seq, hidden):
        # Preprocess the input string to lowercase and remove punctuation marks
        input_seq = str(input_seq).lower()
        input_seq = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', input_seq)

        # Convert the input string to a list of integers, where each integer represents the index of a word in the vocab list
        input_seq = [vocab.index(word) for word in input_seq.split() if word in vocab]

        # Convert the list of integers to a tensor
        input_seq = torch.tensor(input_seq).unsqueeze(0)

        # Reshape the input tensor to have three dimensions
        input_seq = input_seq.unsqueeze(1)

        # Apply the LSTM cell to the input sequence
        hidden = self.init_hidden()
        output, hidden = self.lstm_cell(input_seq, hidden)
        return output, hidden

    def loss(self, output, target_seq):
        # Convert the target string to a list of integers, where each integer represents the index of a word in the vocab list
        target_seq = [vocab.index(word) for word in target_seq.split() if word in vocab]

        # Convert the list of integers to a tensor
        target_seq = torch.tensor(target_seq)

       # Calculate the cross-entropy loss between the output and the target sequence, using a sequence loss function
        output = output.view(-1, output_size)
        target_seq = target_seq.view(-1)
        loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(output, target_seq)
        return loss

    def init_hidden(self):
        # Initialize the hidden state with zeros
        return torch.zeros(self.num_layers, self.batch_size, self.hidden_size).unsqueeze(0)
        
    def train(self, train_data):
        # Loop through each training example
        for input_seq, target_seq in train_data:
            # Convert input and target sequences to tensors
            input_seq = [vocab.index(word) for word in input_seq.split()]
            input_seq = torch.tensor(input_seq)

            target_seq = torch.Tensor(target_seq)

            # Set initial hidden state to all zeros
            hidden = torch.zeros(1, self.hidden_size)

            # Forward pass to get the output sequence
            output, hidden = self.forward(input_seq, hidden)

            # Calculate the loss between the output sequence and the target sequence
            loss = self.loss(output, target_seq)

            # Backward pass to compute the gradients of the loss with respect to the model's parameters
            loss.backward()

            # Update the model's parameters using the optimizer object
            optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(self.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
            optimizer.step()

# Create an instance of the MyLSTMModel class
model = MyLSTMModel(input_size, hidden_size, n_layers, dropout, batch_size)

# Define some example training data
train_data = [("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", "A story as old as time"),
              ("To be or not to be", "That is the question")]

# Train the model on the training data
model.train(train_data)
```

i run the code as a normal python script

my code goal

> The code defines a MyLSTMModel class which extends the nn.Module class from PyTorch.
> This class contains methods for defining the model architecture, initializing the hidden state of the model,
> calculating the loss, training the model, and generating text using the trained model.
> The MyLSTMModel class uses an LSTM (Long Short-Term Memory) layer to process the input sequence
> and generate an output sequence. LSTM is a type of recurrent neural network that is particularly
> well-suited for processing sequences of data. It can remember important information from earlier in
> the sequence and use that information to make predictions about the future. In this case, the LSTM layer
> is used to generate text based on the input sequence.

`*but I get this error when I run the code:*`

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:\path", line 121, in 
> model.train(train_data)
> File "D:\path"", line 95, in train
> target_seq = torch.Tensor(target_seq)
> TypeError: new(): invalid data type 'str'